# How can I pass Session data which is an array of data to another script?

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array

I have two scripts one which stores the details of the users cart using a Session array and a second which is the checkout. I was wondering if its possible for the to pass the session data of the cart to the checkout script without repeating the code in the checkout.

```
     $page_title = 'View Your Shopping Cart';
      include ('includes/header.html');

    // Check if the form has been submitted (to update the cart):
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    // Change any quantities:
    foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $k => $v) {

        // Must be integers!
        $pid = (int) $k;
        $qty = (int) $v;

        if ( $qty == 0 ) { // Delete.
            unset ($_SESSION['cart'][$pid]);
        } elseif ( $qty > 0 ) { // Change quantity.
            $_SESSION['cart'][$pid]['quantity'] = $qty;
        }

    } // End of FOREACH.

        } // End of SUBMITTED IF.

        // Display the cart if it's not empty...
        if (!empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {

    // Retrieve all of the information for the prints in the cart:
    require ('../mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the database.
    $q = "SELECT print_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) AS      artist, print_name FROM artists, prints WHERE artists.artist_id = prints.artist_id AND prints.print_id IN (";
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $pid => $value) {
        $q .= $pid . ',';
    }
    $q = substr($q, 0, -1) . ') ORDER BY artists.last_name ASC';
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

    // Create a form and a table:
    echo '<form action="view_cart.php" method="post">
    <table border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" width="30%"><b>Artist</b></td>
        <td align="left" width="30%"><b>Print Name</b></td>
        <td align="right" width="10%"><b>Price</b></td>
        <td align="center" width="10%"><b>Qty</b></td>
        <td align="right" width="10%"><b>Total Price</b></td>
    </tr>
    ';

    // Print each item...
    $total = 0; // Total cost of the order.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

        // Calculate the total and sub-totals.
        $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['print_id']]['quantity'] * $_SESSION['cart'][$row['print_id']]['price'];
        $total += $subtotal;

        // Print the row:
        echo "\t<tr>
        <td align=\"left\">{$row['artist']}</td>
        <td align=\"left\">{$row['print_name']}</td>
        <td align=\"right\">\${$_SESSION['cart'][$row['print_id']]['price']}</td>
        <td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"3\" name=\"qty[{$row['print_id']}]\" value=\"{$_SESSION['cart'][$row['print_id']]['quantity']}\" /></td>
        <td align=\"right\">$" . number_format ($subtotal, 2) . "</td>
        </tr>\n";

    } // End of the WHILE loop.

    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.

    // Print the total, close the table, and the form:
    echo '<tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="right"><b>Total:</b></td>
        <td align="right">$' . number_format ($total, 2) . '</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update My Cart" /></div>
    </form><p align="center">Enter a quantity of 0 to remove an item.
    <br /><br /><a href="checkout.php">Checkout</a></p>';

} else {
    echo '<p>Your cart is currently empty.</p>';
}

include ('includes/footer.html');
?>



 $page_title = 'Order Confirmation';
 include ('includes/header.html');


 $cid = 1; // Temporary.
```

**This is where I need to get the the total from the view_cart script**

```
    $total = 178.93; // Temporary.

     require ('../mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to the database.

    // Turn autocommit off:
    mysqli_autocommit($dbc, FALSE);

    // Add the order to the orders table...
    $q = "INSERT INTO orders (customer_id, total) VALUES ($cid, $total)";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) {

        // Need the order ID:
    $oid = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);

    // Insert the specific order contents into the database...

    // Prepare the query:
    $q = "INSERT INTO order_contents (order_id, print_id, quantity, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'iiid', $oid, $pid, $qty, $price);

    // Execute each query; count the total affected:
    $affected = 0;
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $pid => $item) {
        $qty = $item['quantity'];
        $price = $item['price'];
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $affected += mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
    }

    // Close this prepared statement:
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    // Report on the success....
    if ($affected == count($_SESSION['cart'])) { // Whohoo!

        // Commit the transaction:
        mysqli_commit($dbc);

        // Clear the cart:
        unset($_SESSION['cart']);

        // Message to the customer:
        echo '<p>Thank you for your order. You will be notified when the items ship.</p>';

        // Send emails and do whatever else.

    } else { // Rollback and report the problem.

        mysqli_rollback($dbc);

        echo '<p>Your order could not be processed due to a system error</p>';
    }

} else { // Rollback and report the problem.

    mysqli_rollback($dbc);

    echo '<p>Your order could not be processed due to a system error.</p>'; 
}

mysqli_close($dbc);

include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If those 2 script are on the same domain and don't have anything prepended then in each file you have to add at the beginning:

```
session_start();
```

Then in one file you can do something like that:

```
$_SESSION['whatever] = 'test data';
```

And in the second script you can run

```
echo $_SESSION['whatever'];
```

and `test data` will be displayed.

In your case in the first script after calculating total you should simple do:

```
$_SESSION['total'] = $total
```

and in the second one you can display it using

```
echo $_SESSION['total'];
```

but you remember you have to put `session_start` at the beginning of both scripts

Comment: I have got session_start() in my header which is included in the scripts. The $_session['cart'] in the view_cart stores the print_id and total. So is it still possible to get that information with $_SESSION['total'] = $total?

Comment: I need to access the the $_session['cart']; then get the total from within this as its a array. Any idea how I can do this

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple SESSION data, you can have `$_SESSION['cart']` and `$_SESSION['total']` and use them together. You can of course assign total value to `$_SESSION['cart']['total']`.